# Can a single 15 ampere power socket be converted into two 15 ampere sockets?

Tags: circuit-design, wiring, circuit-protection

I have an existing 15 ampere socket, but want to install one more 15 ampere socket near it. The electrician suggested to install it from the existing socket.

I have a doubt that since the socket was already designed for 15 amperes, then the wires must have been of the same rating and installing another socket would put a load of 30 amperes on those wires.

Is it possible to install it from the existing outlet?

Am I thinking right?

PS: I am a high school student, so don't know much about how the wiring is done and probably the electrician would be right.

Comment: Possible, yes, but if it is allowed or not depends on national and local electric codes - Most likely a licenced electrician knows best your local regulations, wherever you live.

Comment: The socket doesn't put load on the wiring - the things you plug in put load on the wiring. You're fine to have 30 amps of sockets as long as you don't plug in more than 15 amps of appliances... And if you do, the breaker should trip. Note that (I heard) you can put 15-amp sockets on 20-amp circuits, so maybe you can have up to 20 amps of appliances.

Comment: Several sockets may be wired to the same breaker to allow any to the used up to the breaker rating. It does not increase capacity but it does distribute it more to be shared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

15A is the total current available *on that branch of wiring*, regardless of the number of outlets available.

To exceed this, will cause the circuit breaker powering that branch to open.

If you really want to use 30A of current, you'll have to do it from two *different* devices and two *different* electrical branches; i.e. from two different circuit breakers.

If you are trying to power one device with 30A of current, you'll need a circuit breaker rated for 30A, and wiring and special outlet to match.

Comment: In addition, while you're allowed to install 15A *duplex* outlets on a 20A circuit, you're not allowed to install any 15A sockets (or 20A sockets) on a 30A circuit.